# How to enabled DB as an external object in Heroku

Tags: apex, integration, lightning-connect, heroku, heroku-connect

I'm new to Heroku and I'm trying to wrap my head around with it and I have seen that in demo [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/project/quickstart-lightning-connect/quickstart-lightning-connect2) talks about the exposing the services in Heroku and expose your services like this: `http://orderdb.herokuapp.com/orders.svc`

my question is: What do I need to do in order to expose the Service `svc`, do I have to write an application?
or if you have postgreSQL then it will expose automatically by configuring? those are the answers I'm trying to find, appreciate any help!

Comment: another example of exposing oData service  `http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/`

Comment: You will have to raise a case with Heroku Support and they will enable the heroku connect using which yuo can expose your postgres as oData service. They willl do that for the free accounts as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Heroku Connect for your exposing Postgregs data as Odata Service .Heroku Connect offers out of box feature called Heroku external objects which can be used inside Lightning Connect .

Check these article links for more info

https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/11/13/heroku-external-objects

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/herokuconnect#heroku-external-objects

Comment: Thanks for the links and I have read those blogs and I have postgresql db in heroku but I'm unable to expose that as service to be more clear I have no idea how to expose postgresql db as oData service.

Comment: Do you have Heroku connect in your Heroku instance ? Thats the first step .The second article clearly highlights you need to get Heroku external objects

Comment: yes i do have heroku connect and heroku postgres db but how do i expose the odata service?

Comment: OK this means you did not read article well enough. The article says once you have heruko external object enabled in main navigation you will be able to find settings to get external URL generated automatically. Please read the docs

Comment: You should see external objects in main navigations .This will also have an endpoint for you.

Comment: I'm here going line by line reading https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/herokuconnect#heroku-external-objects it says `When Heroku External Objects is enabled on a Connection` i do not see any options that says `enabled external objects` and I have noticed the heroku do changes in the UI and not necessary matches what it says on the site but if you happens to done this before then it will be easier if you show me the steps, again thanks for your help.

Comment: Nick Kahn ,l did this six months ago for a client ,let me pull screenshots if I have still access to it

Comment: is that true that you have to raise a ticket for db to be enabled as external object? i'm reading on this blog https://samjgarforth.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/connecting-salesforce-to-a-heroku-database/

Comment: Thats correct .I am in the process so I can put some screenshot and I dont have access to my client org anymore .Thanks